# how can we Implement struts framework in jsp web pages

Tags: jsp, struts

Now I have some Jsp pages like validation form ,slide show etc.all of them are client side scripting.Now I want to combine all page link s in one page. also i want run it in tomcat server by implementing struts framework. i setup the server .But i don't know about struts .please explain from starting to End to implement struts.

Comment: You need to go through some basic struts tutorials like [link1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/),[link2](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-tutorials/). Also you need do some search before initiating any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take reference of "Introduction to Struts" book, it will give you the idea of overall architecture with some examples.
You can also read about struts on apache website.

Your use case is an easy one and can be easily implemented once you have the basic idea of struts.